# Factory Method - what exception to throw

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I have an extremely simple factory method that creates a model instance based on some values and conditions of config passed to it.

What i am unsure about is what to do if the factory is unable to create a model instance based on the config it receieves.

First question is, should it return false or null?  or should it throw an exception?

If it should throw an exception what exception should this be.  Im working in PHP here (list of php exceptions http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php )

Comment: throwing an `InvalidArgumentException` would be my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You are the only person who can answer this questions. What should happen isn't defined anywhere.

If you ask me, I would prefer to throw an Exception, call it `YourFactory_ClassNotFoundException` if you want. This would make the calling code look more straightforward as it won't need to test the return value.

---

AFAIK as I know there the following common consensus about this in the PHP core functions and classes:

- `false` should be returned by a method that encounters an error and does not throw Exceptions. (and has no boolean return value like `is_file()`). Those methods are expected to set `errno` and `errmsg` to give user a chance to grab the error message.
- Some of the newer PHP classes will throw an Exception in this case. I would prefer Exceptions for library code.
- `null` is returned if it is a void method without a return statement. This can be conditional

Comment: I know, to a certain extent you are correct.  But there must be some common consensus as to how this is considered best to deal with this situation.  Thanks for you suggestion about exception - im thinkint thats best too at this point

Comment: Have wrote a few lines regarding this.